# NHibernate5: converting dates to local dates when they're persisted without a specific kind

Tags: nhibernate

Now that NHibernate 5 is out, I was wondering what's the recommended approach to load dates as local dates when they're persisted as datetime2 in a SQL Server 2016 database. Until now, dates were interpreted as local (so, the properties ended up with the correct values), but now, the behavior has changed and I'm unable to use the LocalDateTime.

Unfortunately, my donmain's behavior relies in getting those dates automatically loaded as local dates...

Any pointers on how to solve this?

Thanks,

Luis

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't found a way to disable this behavior, I've ended up creating a new type that will simply adjust the format of the data (considering always that it was saved in local format):

```
public class LocalDateTimeTypeNoThrow : LocalDateTimeType {
    public LocalDateTimeTypeNoThrow() {
    }

    public LocalDateTimeTypeNoThrow(DateTimeSqlType sqlType) : base(sqlType) {
    }

    public override string Name => "LocalDateTimeNoThrow";

    public override void Set(DbCommand st, object value, int index, ISessionImplementor session) {
        var dateValue = (DateTime) value;
        //removed throwing from here
        st.Parameters[index].Value = AdjustDateTime(dateValue);
    }
}
```

If there's a better way, please let me know.

Luis